# What does 1. mean in Fortran77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am a new user to Fortran. The Fortran77 .for file I am trying to understand keeps using 1. in the equations. Does that just mean it is a vector of 1's instead of an integer? Thank you very much.

Comment: It probably means that it is a `real` value but without sight of your code it's difficult to be more helpful than that.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry I didn't include any code but I think this is exactly what the author was trying to do. Seems like Fortran90 and Fortran95 don't have this anymore.

Comment: Of course they do. And many other programming languages do soblikewise. There is very little what was removed in Fortran 90 and 95 actually.

Comment: worth a note fortran will automatically convert a literal integer `1` (no dot) to real as needed in many cases.  Some coders throw it everywhere for good measure, some leave it off when they *know* its not needed, and of course some make mistakes by leaving it off when it *is* needed..   Hard to say more without seeing code.

Comment: @VladimirF I see. I guess the main difference is then the size of each line can be longer in Fortran 90 and 95?

Comment: @agentp So when I code I might as well add a dot then?

Comment: Note evn the line length. That is dictated by the source form, not standard revision. You can write Fortran 2008 in the old fixed form which requires short lines.

Comment: Do not add a dot when you need an integer. You must think about datatypes when coding. I really recommend to study first and do serious programming later. Internet tutorials, textbooks, whatever suits you, but choose something not 20 or more years old.

Comment: Yeah, I plan to read the tutorial on the official website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` just forces the compiler to treat it as a REAL type (as opposed to an INTEGER type).  Because of how FORTRAN handles mixed-mode expressions (expressions with both INTEGER and REAL types), you have to be careful when performing those kinds of operations.  If an expression mixes both types, the result will be REAL, however the order in how the sub-expressions are evaluated makes a different.

For example:

`9 / 2 * 3.0 = 12.0`

because `9 / 2` is evaluated as integer arithmetic, thus `9 / 2 = 4`.

Changing the order affects the result:

`3.0 * 9 / 2 = 13.5`

Because the sub expression `3.0 * 9` is evaluated first, and contains a REAL, and forces the result to be REAL.

NOTE: you can fix the problem with the first example by using a `.`:

`9. / 2 * 3.0 = 13.5`

It is better to either make sure all of your operands are REAL, or all are INTEGER to make sure you avoid rounding/truncation errors.

Comment: What about when `1.` appears in an expression such as `1.eq.2`?

Comment: `.eq.` is the equality operator.  In that case you have `1`, `.eq.`, and `2` as the three components of the expression.  So you do NOT have `1.` there.

Comment: There's also the case `     1.` where the `1` is a continuation marker.  My point is, the question doesn't say "I have a token 1." and shows no code: we don't know for certain that these cases don't apply.

Comment: @francescalus Sorry I didn't include more details, but they are just standalone 1.'s like "eta - 1."

Comment: @LifeisGood if you haven't read a FORTRAN tutorial, I strongly recommend it. Here is one: chem.ox.ac.uk/fortran, but there are many other there. That will answer a lot of your questions very quickly. – gariepy 53 mins ago

Comment: @gariepy Thanks for the recommendation! I did consult the Stanford one and a couple of other ones that I found on Google, but this one looks nice as it includes exercises as well.